# Different package import error

Tags: java, import, package

I have a java project that has two packages 'a' and 'b'. A class in 'a' depends on a class in 'b', I compiled the class in 'b' (using javac classname.java) but when I try to compile my class in 'a' the package 'b' isn't recognized. I explicitly import it using a line like this:

```
import b.*;
```

I read online that the full package name is to be given, and that's what I think I'm doing in my import statement given the fact that both my packages are directly under the src folder.

Would anyone have an idea on how to fix this problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you compile the `a` class exactly? Which folder were you in, and what was the exact command?

Comment: I compiled the class in 'a' package using the same command as the class in 'b' package. So I used something like this: (I run this command while I'm in the 'a' folder -cd a- )

javac *.java

Comment: What is the access level of class in package 'b' ?

Comment: @KalyanChavali I'm not sure I understand your question, so my answer may not answer it. 
All my class are public, so accessable from any other package

Comment: Check if you declared the packages (in the first line of your files, the definition must match the folder structure) and then compile from your project root.

Comment: I wasn't compiling from the root folder, that was my issue. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you may be doing is compiling from the package folder itself. If so, then you will need to exit directory so that you are instead inside the source directory, and then compile with the following command:

```
javac a/ClassInA.java
```

Where "ClassInA" is the name of the class in the "a" package.

Answer (score 1):

The below would have been the error you would have got .

```
C:\Users\id831496\Desktop\New folder\a>javac ClassA.java
ClassA.java:3: package b does not exist
import b.*;
^
ClassA.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ClassB
location: class a.ClassA
ClassB classB = null;
^
2 errors
```

What needs to be done is add an classpath argument like below

```
C:\Users\id831496\Desktop\New folder\a>javac -cp ..\b\* ClassA.java

C:\Users\id831496\Desktop\New folder\a>
```

Comment: I tried doing it at first but I couldn't, I didn't have 15 points, I just got them now though x)